# What is the optimal naming convention for test files in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am looking for an optimal naming convention for python test files that ease the usage of different test frameworks (unittest, note, pyunit, ...) and also that is friendly with test auto-discovery for these tools.

I just want a clear set of recomandation that would require minimal configuration for tools.

- Tests directory name? `test` or `tests`?
- Where to put the tests? in module/testdir or module/../testdir
- Test filenames using underscore or dash? test_0.py or test-0.py

I know, I have too much time :)

Comment: The "-" has creates problems in Python because it violates the rules that map file names to module names.  **Never** use anything other than a valid Python identifier as part of a Python file name.

Answer (score 26):

Don't call the directory `test` or it will conflict with the built-in `test` package.

The naming conventions are defined in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). See the 'Naming Conventions' section. Underscores are better than hyphens!

The layout of your package is a bit more flexible. I tend to do the following:

```
package
|-- package
|  |-- __init__.py
|  `-- <etc>
|-- tests
|  `-- <etc>
|-- setup.py
|-- README
|-- LICENCE
`-- <etc>
```

This keeps the tests separate from the package itself. Installing the package using setup.py can install just the source, which keeps people's interpreters tidy. The tests are there for developers that need them when they get the package source.

You should look at [The Hitch Hiker's Guide to Packaging](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for more info on Python packages.

Comment: Thanks! Only one sub-question: what if I have several submodules, this means that I will have to combine all tests in the same directory? Or I should only move them to subdirs like `/tests/a/`?

Comment: You can honestly go either way on this one. Django uses the approach I've mentioned and I think many at least put them in one place. However, Django applications have the tests spread throughout and I'm sure many people do it this way too. I would lean towards having the tests in one place over scattered throughout (be that within or outside the source) but I can't think of a strong argument to give you either way :)

Comment: The argument for keeping tests in a separate directory is completely dependent on aesthetics. I agree with @adamnfish about placing them separately in a directory structure that mirrors the code - that way it is easier for a human to find specific tests to run (as I do all the time during development). But if you are prone to changing project structure (adding and removing modules/files) you might miss updating the tests - but you will see failures, so you'll know!

Answer (score 2):

It will depends of the tool you're using to run your tests.

If you're using [nosetest](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/#), the philosophy used to detect test is pretty simple :

> [If it looks like a test, it’s a test.](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/finding_tests.html)

If you're using [py.test](http://pytest.org), the conventions are [pretty open too](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#:%7E:text=Conventions%20for%20Python%20test%20discovery,file%20names%20or%20node%20ids.).

About the "where to put test" question, personnaly, I prefer to store tests in a subdirectory in each package to be sure to not forgot to run/touch the tests when someone edit the code ;)